# Jenkins hpi plugin has too many jar files

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar, jenkins-plugins

I have created a new Jenkins plugin using netbeans. The plugin is working as expected, however the size of the .hpi file generated is too huge. I have only 1 jar file that needs to be added as a dependency.

However, when I see the `.hpi` that was generated by netbeans it has over 90 jar files. I.e It seems to be adding dependencies that are already available on Jenkins server.

The .hpi file is created by netbeans in the target directory of the project. After I deploy the .hpi using `Manage plugins` link, I can see the `.hpi` in the `.jenkins/plugins` directory. Some of the jar files from `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the plugin are:

```
aether-api-0.9.0.M3.jar
cdi-api-1.0.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
doxia-decoration-model-1.0.jar
doxia-site-renderer-1.0.jar
```

Is there a way to restrict this/package it more elegantly so that the plugin only has the jars that are needed ?
If yes, How can I do that using Netbeans ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to building your plugin, did you clean up the artifacts?

```
mvn clean
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephane.. that did solve the problem.. I also had some unexpected entries in POM.. After removing those and doing a clean run, the jars reduced.!

Comment: Note that you can clean+build using `mvn clean install` directly.

Answer (score 1):

- you keep only required dependencies on your POM file under your dependency section of POM
- Cleanup old artifacts using  as suggested by Stephane, before building
  your plugin.

Comment: Thanks @DevD.. that did solve the problem.. Indeed there were some entries which I thought were mandatory. After removing those and doing a clean-build the jars were gone!